# Help with Blackberry app publishing - supported devices

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-world

I need to publish BB app to the App World. I set that "Required Device Software" is 4.7.0 or higher. Then the list of "Supported Devices" appeared (10 devices), I marked all of them and sent the app to the approval process.

A day later the app was rejected and I was suggested to alter the list of supported devices.

So my questions are:
1. Does BB Vendor Portal automatically list supported devices once I choose the mimimum version of required device software?
2. If the answer to Q1 is no: Do I really have to test the app if it works on all devices? I have never seen such pain in other mobile market sites.

If I have to test the app for all devices, I assume that I have to download emulator for all those devices. Am I right or there's a quicker solution?

This was my first attempt to publish a BB app so I hope someone with more experience will be able to help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't published to AppWorld yet, but I have written software to support multiple models and multiple OS versions.

OS 4.7 is specific to the Storm, which is a touch screen only device. Higher versions of the OS support models without a touch screen. Without seeing what RIM actually said I can't be sure, but it may be that if you wrote your application for the Storm OS 4.7 it won't run satisfactorily on a Bold II OS 5.0 or 6.0.

Comment: It is simple remote web start app. You click on it and it start a remote URL. Just that. As simple as possible. In a previous post on BB (a month ago or so) a guy suggested me to code the app in IDE 4.7 because it will be supported by all upper versions.

Comment: Also, do you know the answer to Q1?

Comment: No, I don't know the answer to Q1. You could use the same argument to code the app in 4.6, 4.5, 4.3, etc. In fact, if you aren't supporting the Storm I would suggest 5.0 as better IDE to use since 5.0 is available for the Storm.